# Unable to install encfs

Tags: encfs

tried to install encfs.
After adding repository, and update gave command in terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-encfs-manager
```

Am getting response  .. `Unable to locate package gnome-encfs-manager`

Answer (score 1):

From the ubuntu community, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption

> Gnome Encfs Manager
>
> There is also GUI solution - Gnome Encfs Manager (homepage: >http://www.libertyzero.com/GEncfsM/, project page at Launchpad: >https://launchpad.net/gencfsm).
>
> To install it copy/paste the following line into a terminal and hit enter:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gencfsm && sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-encfs-manager`

Comment: Per http://www.libertyzero.com/GEncfsM/, "Ubuntu 19.10 and later are currently not supported due to the removal of the old gnome keyring API" (as of 11/5/2020). For Ubuntu 20.04, see Molch Encfs Manager (https://moritzmolch.com/apps/mencfsm.html)